# iOS App Memory Warnings

Tags: ios, memory-management, warnings, clang-static-analyzer

I have about 500+ memory warnings after running the static analyzer.  Is this something I should be concerned about and spend time fixing or will it really not help improve app crashes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

500+ is way too many to ignore. Even if the 90% of the warnings are bogus, that still leaves 50 warnings that are serious and require your attention!

Remember, this app will be running on a mobile device with limited memory. I would highly recommend fixing these to prevent crashes, never mind getting it approved for the app store.

Comment: It's been approved and downloaded by tens of thousands of devices :( the app crashes frequently and we aren't sure why.  Do you think fixing these memory warnings will help?

Comment: It will quite probably help; if you try to use too much memory and then fail to release some back when warned then iOS will force close your app — which is a crash for all intents and purposes. So ensuring you're not accidentally letting memory you no longer use remain allocated could be the fix. The warnings are presumably mostly about potential leaks?

Comment: There are 3 types: 1. Memory (Core Foundation/Objective-C) 2. Logic error and 3. Dead store

Comment: Wow, it was approved with that many warnings? To answer your question, I believe solving the memory warnings would drastically decrease the number of crashes. The fact that you are having frequent crashes should tell you that something is wrong and it is most likely the memory if you have that many warnings. I have not used static analyzer but the site says it is still in production, so I would recommend comparing its results with those that you get from XCode's analyze function and your Mac's instruments application. Tracing the problems may reveal that it's only a few lines of problem code.

Comment: Sorry, we are using the built in XCode analyze function.

Comment: Actually, I did not realize the analyzer in XCode was called that. My apologies. Either way, this app you have needs some fixing. Here are some links you may find helpful:
[Analysis](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#featuredarticles/StaticAnalysis/FeaturedArticle.html) and 
[Debugging](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/Debugging/Debugging.html)